# Configuring Protractor with WebStorm

Tags: protractor, webstorm

I am new to Protractor and WebStorm.

Please help me in configuring Protractor with WebStorm and executing scripts successfully.

I did try to configure, but then it does not identify sendKeys function.

Comment: please post your error details and the steps you tried in order to get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebStorm provides no support for protractor (if you miss it, please vote for [WEB-9236](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9236)). But you can use Node.js Run configuration to run it. It would looks as follows:

```
JavaScript file: path/to/protractor
Application parameters: [options] protractor.conf.js
```

[image]